# Best way to match a large list against strings in python

Tags: python, list, pattern-matching

I have a python list that contains about 700 terms that I would like to use as metadata for some database entries in Django. I would like to match the terms in the list against the entry descriptions to see if any of the terms match but there are a couple of issues. My first issue is that there are some multiword terms within the list that contain words from other list entries. An example is:

```
Intrusion
Intrusion Detection
```

I have not gotten very far with re.findall as it will match both Intrusion and Intrusion Detection in the above example. I would only want to match Intrusion Detection and not Intrusion.

Is there a better way to do this type of matching? I thought maybe maybe about trying NLTK but it didn't look like it could help with this type of matching.

Edit:

So to add a little more clarity, I have a list of 700 terms such as firewall or intrusion detection. I would like to try to match these words in the list against descriptions that I have stored in a database to see if any match, and I will use those terms in metadata. So if I have the following string:

```
There are many types of intrusion detection devices in production today.
```

and if I have a list with the following terms:

```
Intrusion
Intrusion Detection
```

I would like to match 'intrusion detection', but not 'intrusion'. Really I would like to also be able to match singular/plural instances too, but I may be getting ahead of myself. The idea behind all of this is to take all of the matches and put them in a list, and then process them.

Comment: Can you provide some example data? The question is a little unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need more flexibility to match entry descriptions, you can combine `nltk` and `re`

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
import re
```

let's say you have different descriptions of the same event ie. *a rewrite of the system*. You can use `nltk.stem` to capture *rewrite, rewriting, rewrites*, singular and plural forms etc.

```
master_list = [
    'There are many types of intrusion detection devices in production today.',
    'The CTO approved a rewrite of the system',
    'The CTO is about to approve a complete rewrite of the system',
    'The CTO approved a rewriting',
    'Breaching of Firewalls'
]

terms = [
    'Intrusion Detection',
    'Approved rewrite',
    'Firewall'
]

stemmer = PorterStemmer()

# for each term, split it into words (could be just one word) and stem each word
stemmed_terms = ((stemmer.stem(word) for word in s.split()) for s in terms)

# add 'match anything after it' expression to each of the stemmed words
# join result into a pattern string
regex_patterns = [''.join(stem + '.*' for stem in term) for term in stemmed_terms]
print(regex_patterns)
print('')

for sentence in master_list:
    match_obs = (re.search(pattern, sentence, flags=re.IGNORECASE) for pattern in regex_patterns)
    matches = [m.group(0) for m in match_obs if m]
    print(matches)
```

**Output:**

```
['Intrus.*Detect.*', 'Approv.*rewrit.*', 'Firewal.*']

['intrusion detection devices in production today.']
['approved a rewrite of the system']
['approve a complete rewrite of the system']
['approved a rewriting']
['Firewalls']
```

**EDIT:**

To see which of the `terms` caused the match:

```
for sentence in master_list:
    # regex_patterns maps directly onto terms (strictly speaking it's one-to-one and onto)
    for term, pattern in zip(terms, regex_patterns):
        if re.search(pattern, sentence, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
            # process term (put it in the db)
            print('TERM: {0} FOUND IN: {1}'.format(term, sentence))
```

**Output:**

```
TERM: Intrusion Detection FOUND IN: There are many types of intrusion detection devices in production today.
TERM: Approved rewrite FOUND IN: The CTO approved a rewrite of the system
TERM: Approved rewrite FOUND IN: The CTO is about to approve a complete rewrite of the system
TERM: Approved rewrite FOUND IN: The CTO approved a rewriting
TERM: Firewall FOUND IN: Breaching of Firewalls
```

Comment: This solution looks great, but is there a way to determine which entry from 'terms' caused the match? That is the information that I am trying to insert in the database.

Comment: @ajt use the fact that `regex_patterns` was built from `terms`, if there is a match process `term`, see the edit

Answer (score 0):

This question is unclear, but from what I understand you have a Master List of terms. Say one term per line. Next you have a list of test data, where some of the test data will be in the master list, and some wont. You want to see if the test data is in the master list and if it is perform a task.

Assuming your Master List looks like this

> Intrusion Detection 
>   Firewall 
>   FooBar

and your Test Data Looks like this

> Intrusion 
>   Intrusion Detection 
>   foo 
>   bar

this simple script should lead you in the right direction

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys 

def main():
  '''useage tester.py masterList testList'''   


  #open files
  masterListFile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
  testListFile = open(sys.argv[2], 'r')

  #bulid master list
  # .strip() off '\n' new line
  # set to lower case. Intrusion != intrusion, but should.
  masterList = [ line.strip().lower() for line in masterListFile ]
  #run test
  for line in testListFile:
    term = line.strip().lower()
    if term  in masterList:
      print term, "in master list!"
      #perhaps grab your metadata using a like %%
    else:
      print "OH NO!", term, "not found!"

  #close files
  masterListFile.close()
  testListFile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

> OH NO! intrusion not found! 
>   intrusion detection in master list! 
>   OH NO! foo not found! 
>   OH NO! bar not found!

there are several other ways to do this, but this should point you in the right direction. if your list is large (700 really isn't that large) consider using a dict, I feel they quicker. especially if yo plan to query a database. perhaps a dictionary structure could look like {term: information about term}